# On page load, set it to a variable or filtered variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On page load, "pages" should either equal the prop "page" or the prop 'relatedPages' BUT filtered: "filteredRelatedPage".

I have it set up below, but its not working. I get that on page load filteredRelatedPage is initially and empty array, but how else would you structure it?

```
function RelatedPages({
  data: { page, relatedPages }
}) {
  const filteredRelatedPages = filteredPages && {
    items: relatedPage
      .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
      .filter((item) => !router.asPath.includes(item.slug))
      .slice(0, 5)
  };

  const pages = 
    page?.length > 0 ? page : filteredRelatedPages
  ;

  return (<>{pages}</>) 
}
```